# Selenium C# - setting profile path

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

I want to use a specific firefox profile stored in a folder.

My code so far:

```
        IWebDriver driver;
        string pathToCurrentUserProfiles = @"C:\FirefoxProfile\";
        string[] pathsToProfiles = Directory.GetDirectories(pathToCurrentUserProfiles, "*.default");

        FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(pathsToProfiles[0]);
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);

        driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://localhost");
```

Visual Studio though shows me this error:

```
Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxProfile' to 'OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxOptions'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a FirefoxOptions object and set the `Profile` property:

```cs
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(pathsToProfiles[0]);

FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions()
{
    Profile = profile
};

driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

You can infer this solution by looking at the arguments that the FirefoxDriver constructor accepts.